# Microsoft Access decimal representation

Tags: ms-access, decimal

I have a MS Access 2010 database with a products table.  The price column is a single datatype with format set to Fixed(2).  There are certain values that are not being represented correctly, and I've no idea why.  For example, one price is shown in the table as 1.52.  However, if I export to Excel, or view it in a form with the Currency format, I see that Access has really stored `1.51999998092651`.  No matter what I do, I can't seem to change the value to represent the `0.20` correctly.

I know that computers store reals as approximations, but this seems rather ridiculous.  Any ideas what's going on here and how I can fix it?

Comment: Is there any reason you could not use the Currency data type in the table itself?

Comment: The currency type is storing the `1.51999998092651` value too. the only difference is I can *see* it's storing it like that in the table itself.

Comment: Ouch. I generally truncate decimals at the time of update or insertion. Division is what gets ya. Sorry I don't know more than that =(

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing.  Even we manually enter 1.52, Access is storing it as shown.

Comment: Wow that's painful. Sorry I can't be of any help =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace 'Single' datatype to 'Currency', or at least to 'Double'.

Floating point numbers in common do not have accurate binary representation. Certainly 'Double' type will have less mistakes. So you need to use fixed point numbers, named 'Currency' in ms access. But they have limited precession 15 digits before and 4 digits after point.

P.S. You have to change **type**, not **format**.

Comment: I up voted this. The simple solution here is to use a currency column. If that column is storing a funny number, then what is the "source" of these columns and how are they being created?

Comment: This answer does not deserve the upvote, since I already stated that I observed the same behavior with the Currency data type.  However, converting to the double data type *does* seem to fix the issue, so I've marked it as correct.  I can't believe neither the Single nor Currency data types can accurately represent even something like 4.1.  Kind of ridiculous...

Comment: 'Currency' can. May be you are doing something wrong. Try to create new table ant type 4.1 into 'Currency' field - you will get exact 4.1